# c# Math/Formula Calculation

Tags: c#, math, formula

I have an interesting problem i am trying to solve in my c# project, my head is hurting so any advice would be greatly appreciated

Basically i have an employee that works on a 3 week cycle

wk 1 - they work mon

wk 2 - they work wed

### wk 3 - they work fri

wk 4 - they work mon

wk 5 - they work wed
.. and so on

I need a formula that will show me what day they worked on any given week, ie what day would they work on week 49 of employment?

Any thoughts on how i may solve this equation?

Cheers
Anthony

Comment: You're going to need to post some source code/show what you tried.

Comment: This isn't a difficult problem, but SO only helps with problems that you've attempted to fix. Write code that tries to achieve what you want, and if you're struggling, post your code attempt (with an explanation of what you want, and what you're currently getting) so that we can help. But I'll drop some hints: [the day of the week](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) and [the modulo operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator).

Comment: Do you know what the `%` operator does?

Comment: **There is always an easier problem that you can solve**. Can you write a method that takes an integer and returns an integer, such that if you give it 1 you get 0 back. If you give it 2, you get 1.  3 goes to 2. 4 goes to 0. 5 goes to 1. 6 goes to 2. 7 goes to 0. And so on.  Write that method first. Can you see how to use that method to help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comment we can use modulo (%) operator in your formula.

`int dayInt = (nthWeek % 3)`;

> This will give you result in 0, 1, 2. 0 - friday, 1 - Monday, 2-
>   wednesday

Here is the code:

```
int nthWeek = 49;

    int result = (nthWeek % 3);

    switch(result)
    {
        case 0:
            Console.WriteLine("Worker is working on Friday");
        break;

        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Worker is working on Monday");
        break;

        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Worker is working on Wednesday");
        break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Worker is working on other day");
        break;
    }
```

Implementation: [DotnetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cMAaxP)

Comment: Thanks Prasad, that works for me, apologies for not posting my code but it was actually the correct operator (%) that i was after, without this i wasnt making any progress

Comment: Happy coding @AnthonyKallay

Answer (score 0):

This will give the desired output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static void WhichDaysAreTheyWorking()
{
   List<String> daysOfTheWeek = new List<String>();
   daysOfTheWeek.Add("Monday");
   daysOfTheWeek.Add("Tuesday");
   daysOfTheWeek.Add("Wednesday");
   daysOfTheWeek.Add("Thursday");
   daysOfTheWeek.Add("Friday");
   daysOfTheWeek.Add("Saturday");
   daysOfTheWeek.Add("Sunday");
   int i = 0;
   for (int week = 1; week < 50; week++)
   {
      if (daysOfTheWeek[i].Equals("Friday"))
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Week # " + week + " They work " + daysOfTheWeek[i]);
          Console.WriteLine("Week # " + (week + 1) + " They work " + daysOfTheWeek[i - 4]);
          i = 2;
          week = week + 1;
          continue;
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Week # " + week + "They work " + daysOfTheWeek[i]);
          i = i + 2;
      }
   }
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```